# Elementary OS 0.4 Loki (64bit): How to reinstall app center?

Tags: release-loki, appcenter

I am trying to figure out how to reinstall App Center, I want to think it worked in the beginning, but cant remember...

```
sudo apt install appcenter
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/ca.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_main_binary-amd64_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Comment: Just curious - why you're using such an old release?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not able to install app center for the problem with Merged List.

Try to follow [these steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err) to resolve the Merge List before installing app center again.